# Are these inequalities true?

Tags: inequality

The following is a question regarding an inequality direction.

With $a,b,c $ being real and non-negative. Can I say that following is ALWAYS true.

$$1+(a+b+c)^2 \le 2(a+b+c)^2$$

What about the following 
$$\sqrt{b^2+c^2} \ge \max\{b,c\}$$

Looking forward for your input. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

The first inequality is equivalent to

$$(a+b+c)^2\ge 1$$

which is obviously not always true (e.g., Take $a=b=c=0$.  Then $(a+b+c)^2=0 <1$).

The second inequality is always true since both inequalities

$$\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\ge |b|\ge b$$

and

$$\sqrt{b^2+c^2}\ge |c|\ge c$$

hold for all real $b$ and $c$.

Comment: thanks do you have any idea about the second inequality?

Comment: It is always true.

Comment: You're welcome!  My pleasure.